How to detect the time of last boot in a powershell script?
How do I get the most recent windows boot time in a powershell script?
Currently I'm using this line
Get-WmiObject win32_operatingsystem -ComputerName myserver | Select-Object @{LABEL='LastBootUpTime';EXPRESSION={$_.ConverttoDateTime($_.lastbootuptime)}}

It works (in the sense that it returns a valid date) but the date doesn't appear to be sensible.
Background - I've just shut down the server for 5 minutes in expectation of a brief power outage, after re-booting the above expression returns  11/12/2024 03:31:04 (or about 2 weeks ago).
This date may (or may not) be a boot time, but it's definitely not the last reboot I did a few hours ok. So, either this is returning something other than the boot time, OR a brief power-down doesn't count as a re-boot (somehow).
Any ideas?
UPDATE...
Ok, I've tried the following
(Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_OperatingSystem).LastBootUpTime

and
Get-CimInstance -ClassName win32_operatingsystem | select csname, lastbootuptime

They all give me the same two-week-old boot date.
I think the true question is really why wasn't the re-boot recorded in the event logs.

You should not use Get-WmiObject anymore. Instead use Get-CimInstance -ClassName CIM_OperatingSystem -ComputerName myserver | Select-Object -Property LastBootUpTime! This way you don't even have to convert the value anymore. Did you really run the command again or did you maybe save the output in a variable or something like this? ... how did you shutdown the server? ... did you shut it down or did you suspend it?

Can you (manually) find the event back in the event log? If not, it is not a programming issue but a https://superuser.com/ question.

You claim it does not work but you accepted the answer!?  ‍♂️  ... how exactly did you reboot the system? Are you sure DNS is working properly?

@Olaf - I'm trying to close the question because the basic premise is incorrect. I started by claiming my powershell function isn't working, but since all answers here give the same result I know realise the function is returning the date it should, but the re-boot isn't been recorded in the event log correctly. New question will appear on superuser soon!

So you may delete the question completely  .... ‍♂️

Instead of Get-WmiObject, which is deprecated, use this:
$lastBoot = (Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_OperatingSystem).LastBootUpTime


I use the following as a uname-like command. The LastBootUpTime is near the end.
[CmdletBinding()]
param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
    [string[]] $NetworkPrefixes = @('10','192')
)

$unameInfo = Get-CimInstance Win32_OperatingSystem

$csInfo = Get-CimInstance Win32_ComputerSystem
$unameInfo | Add-Member -NotePropertyName 'UserName' -NotePropertyValue $csInfo.UserName
$unameInfo | Add-Member -NotePropertyName 'TotalPhysicalMemory' `
    -NotePropertyValue ('{0:0.##}' -f ($csInfo.TotalPhysicalMemory / 1GB) + ' GiB')

$unameInfo | Add-Member -NotePropertyName 'LogonServer' -NotePropertyValue $Env:LOGONSERVER
$unameInfo | Add-Member -NotePropertyName 'UserDomain' -NotePropertyValue $Env:USERDOMAIN

$DisplayVersion = (Get-Item "HKLM:SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion").GetValue('DisplayVersion')
if ([string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($DisplayVersion)) { $DisplayVersion = 'unknown'}
$unameInfo | Add-Member -NotePropertyName 'DisplayVersion' -NotePropertyValue $DisplayVersion

#$IpAddresses = ((Get-NetIPAddress).IPAddress | Where-Object { ($_ -replace '^([0-9a-fA-F]+).*','$1') -in $NetworkPrefixes }) -join ', '
$IpAddresses = ([System.Net.DNS]::GetHostByName($null)).AddressList.IPAddressToString -join ', '

$unameInfo | Add-Member -NotePropertyName 'IPAddresses' -NotePropertyValue $IpAddresses

$AssetTag = (Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_SystemEnclosure).SMBIOSAssetTag
$unameInfo | Add-Member -NotePropertyName 'AssetTag' -NotePropertyValue $AssetTag
$unameInfo | Add-Member -NotePropertyName 'PSVersion' -NotePropertyValue $PSVersionTable.PSVersion.ToString()
$unameInfo | Add-Member -NotePropertyName 'Uptime' -NotePropertyValue ((Get-Date) - $unameInfo.LastBootUpTime).ToString()

$Properties = @('CSName', 'AssetTag', 'IPAddresses', 'UserDomain', 'UserName', 'LogonServer',
    'Caption', 'Version', 'PSVersion', 'DisplayVersion',
    'BuildType', 'OSArchitecture', 'TotalPhysicalMemory', 'LastBootUpTime', 'Uptime'
)
$unameInfo | Select-Object -Property $Properties #| Format-Table -AutoSize


Wow. Do you really feel like this is a good answer to the question?  ‍♂️
